# Send the function with arguments to the model

Tags: php, function, model-view-controller

I have several index pages
And I put the header page separately
I want the name of each page to be sent to the header
How can I do it, thank you?

```
model::setnameisset('home');
```

and model.php page

```
     function setnameisset($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
```

Now I want it to be saved in the header page instead of the title tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <base href="<?= URL ?>">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"> -->
  <title></title>
   </head>
```

Now how do I call that function?

Comment: Your `setnameisset()`-method seems pointless if all it does is to return the value you passed in? Either way, you haven't posted enough code/info for us to know where to even begin. What _exactly_ are you trying to do, and how is the posted code related (other than having a `<title>`-tag)? How are you loading that header? What does your `model` have to do with it? When are you making your method call and what do you expect it to do? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get some idea of what we need.

Comment: _"Now I want it to be saved in the header page instead of the title tag"_ - What does that actually mean?

Comment: I sent the complete answer, thank you for taking a look

Answer (score -1):

See I have several pages like contact page or home page
And I put the header in a page and included it in these pages
The structure is m v c
I just want to send the name of the page or the keyword tag to the header so that it opens with that name during execution.

For example, my index or contact file

```
 <?php model::nametag('homepage'); ?>
<body id="page-top">
</body>
```

Now I have a model file in the core folder
My controller file is like this

```
class Controller
{
function __construct()
{
}
function view($viewurl,$data=[],$noincludeheader = '',$noincludefooter = ''){
if ($noincludeheader =='') {
  require_once ('views/share-base/header.php'); //panel header
}
require_once ('views/'.$viewurl.'.php'); //panel main page
if ($noincludefooter =='')
{
  require_once ('views/share-base/footer.php'); // panel footer
}
}
function model($modelUrl){
require_once ('models/model_'.$modelUrl.'.php');
$classname='model_'.$modelUrl;
$this->model = new $classname;
}
}
```

And my model file is like this

```
public function nametag($name)
     {
         return $name;
     }
```

It's so easy, I just want to be placed in any file, a name should be passed to the header page, I don't know how to use the function.